# Angular template conditional logic without dom element

Tags: css, angularjs

Does anyone know of a way that I can conditionally put content inside of a textarea with angular?

What I'd really like to do is something like:

```
<textarea>
  <span ng-if="showHeader">
    Header
  </span>
</textarea>
```

or in php it would look something like:

```
<textarea>
  <? if (show_header): ?>
    Header
  <? endif ?>
</textarea>
```

I know that it's a kind of a strange use case, and I'm not entirely sure it's possible. I suppose it's a kind of larger question about being able to use conditional logic outside of DOM elements. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<textarea>
       {{ showHeader == true ? 'Header' : ''}}
</textarea>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6ZUGod5gWnl8S1dquZO8?p=preview)

```
<textarea ng-bind="showHeader == true ? 'Header' : ''">
</textarea>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/0S1b8olwI2B711BqUPBY?p=preview)

Comment: I picked this one because it actually allows for conditional logic inside the template.

Answer (score 2):

Just have this as the html

```
<textarea>{{data.header}}</textarea>
```

then somewhere in your controller have

```
//in this case $scope.data is an object to hold our data for the view
$scope.data.header = show_header?header:"";
```